GraphQL interprets node identifiers as string instead of integers
I am trying to add Relay/Global Object Identification to my GraphQL query.
My type looks like this:
[Node]
public class Speaker
{
    [ID]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Bio { get; set; }

    public virtual string? WebSite { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SessionSpeaker> SessionSpeakers { get; set; } = new List<SessionSpeaker>();
}

My query is the following:
query {
  node(id: 1) {
    id
    ... on Speaker {
      bio
      id
      name
      webSite
    }
  }
}

I receive the following error message:
The argument literal representation is HotChocolate.Language.IntValueNode which is not compatible with the request literal type HotChocolate.Language.StringValueNode

I changed Id to be string instead of int. I receive the following error message:
query {
  node(id: "1") {
    id
    ... on Speaker {
      bio
      id
      name
      webSite
    }
  }
}

Unable to decode the id string.

According to the documentation, Relay ids do have a special format. TypeName + id in base64. When I give id like "Speaker1" -> Base 64 "U3BlYWtlcjE=" I get a different error message:
Unable to decode the id string.

query {
  node(id: "U3BlYWtlcjE=") {
    ... on Speaker {
      bio
      id
      name
      webSite
    }
  }
}

What am I doing wrong? In what kind of format should I supply the id then?
I am writing a graphql endpoint for a service, which uses int for Id. What would be the best way to do it?

"Relay ids do have a special format. TypeName + id in base64" you don't seem to have tried that with the TypeName whatever that is.

Type name is "Speaker", and id is "1". Speaker1 -> U3BlYWtlcjE=. I supplied this example above. It is not good still, and this is my issue. I can not figure it out, why does it not work.

I have no idea if that is the right format, you'd have to look at the docs, which you haven't provided.

I haven't provided the docs, because I can not provide them. The official documentation did have a backend code only without example query. I found the TypeName+id format in a different stackoverflow thread, which also did not work for me.

First write a Query that gets all Speakers.
In the response of this query should be a ID field present that cotains the Relay Id generated by HotChocolate. Use that for your node interface instead of stiching it together by hand
